# ReactJs nested list collapse for only one list item

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am trying to make a collapse sublist using material UI and ReactJS, I have followed the examples in the material-UI list.
the problem is when click on one list item to expand the other list items expands also like the image below:

[image: llist of two items]

this the code:

```
   return (
        <List component="nav"
              aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
              subheader={
                  <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
                      Nested List Items
                  </ListSubheader>
              }>
            {items.map((item, index, list) => (
                <Fragment key={item.id}>
                    <ListItem button key={item.id} onClick={handleClick}>
                        <ListItemAvatar>
                            <Avatar>
                                <img className={classes.icon} src={`images/icon/${item.category || 'default'}.svg`}
                                     alt=""/>
                            </Avatar>
                        </ListItemAvatar>
                        <ListItemText primary={item.name}/>
                        {open ? <ExpandLess/> : <ExpandMore/>}
                    </ListItem>
                    <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                        <List component="div" disablePadding>
                            <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                                <ListItemIcon>
                                    <LensIcon style={{color: changeColorStatus(item)}}/>
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary="Status"/>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                                <IconButton onClick={(event) => onMenuClick(event.currentTarget, item.id)}>
                                    <MoreVertIcon/>
                                </IconButton>
                            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                        </List>
                    </Collapse>
                    {index < list.length - 1 ? <Divider/> : null}
                </Fragment>
            ))}
        </List>
    );
}

  const handleClick = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using a single `boolean` to determine the open state of several list items. What you should do is use an `int` instead and assign the `item.id` to it.

So you need to change the `handleClick` event to the following:

```
<ListItem button key={item.id} onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}>
...
```

As for the handler:

```
const handleClick = (itemID) => {
  setOpen(itemID);
  // or simply setState({ openItemID: itemID });
};
```

For your render now you will have to change the conditions.

```
{openItemID === item.id ? <ExpandLess/> : <ExpandMore/>}
```

And

```
<Collapse in={openItemID === item.id} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
...
```

Comment: thanks, guys the problem is almost solved, there is a small issue the open item doesn't closed when click on the arrow

Comment: @Alloylo to close the item just call the same `handleClick` for the arrow and send a 0, no item.id is 0 (I assume) so all of the items will be closed.

Comment: @Alloylo Or in handleClick() you can check if(itemID === openItemID) : setOpen(0) ? setOpen(itemID)