# ReactJS Nested List Issue

Tags: reactjs, nested-lists, expand

My nested list in ReactJS opens all sublists when I expand
one category

[Collapsed List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o28A.png)
[Expand List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kF3t.png)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ListSubheader from '@mui/material/ListSubheader';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';
import ExpandLess from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';


export default function SideBar() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  
    const handleClick = () => {
      setOpen(!open);
    };
  
    return (
      <List
        sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}
        component="nav"
        aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
        subheader={
          <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
            courses
          </ListSubheader>
        }
      >
        <ListItemButton  onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          <ListItemText primary="Course 1" />
          {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItemButton>
        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <List component="div" disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
              <ListItemText primary="Research Paper" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </List>
        </Collapse>

        <ListItemButton>
          <ListItemText primary="Course 2" />
          {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItemButton>

        <ListItemButton  onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          <ListItemText primary="Course 3" />
          {open  ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItemButton>
        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <List component="div" disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
              <ListItemText primary="Exams" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </List>
        </Collapse>

      </List>
    );
  }
```

I found the problem might be that I am using an binary operator to open all the lists. I found this solution [ReactJs nested list collapse for only one list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66857203/reactjs-nested-list-collapse-for-only-one-list-item) but was unable to implement it properly. Any ideas on what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is all the list components share a single state. Make `ListItemButton` and `Collapse` a single component called `MyCollapseComponent` which holds toggle logic:

```
const MyCollapsibleComponent = ({ course, content }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ListItemButton onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        <ListItemText primary={course} />
        {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
      </ListItemButton>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
            <ListItemText primary={content} />
          </ListItemButton>
        </List>
      </Collapse>
    </>
  );
};
```

Then create individual `MyCollapsibleComponent` providing the props you want:

```
export default function SideBar() {
  return (
    <List
      sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: "background.paper" }}
      component="nav"
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      subheader={
        <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
          courses
        </ListSubheader>
      }
    >
      <MyCollapsibleComponent course="Course 1" content="Research Paper" />
      <MyCollapsibleComponent course="Course 2" content="" />
      <MyCollapsibleComponent course="Course 3" content="Exams" />
    </List>
  );
}
```

Code Sandbox Demo

[image: Edit morning-glade-dxwx5k]